# reinterpret_cast from rvalue to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, standards-compliance

Just a simple does it compile test.
gcc accepts the following while clang and msvc reject it: https://godbolt.org/z/DlUasL

```
float test()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<float&&>(0x7F800000);
}
```

Which one is right according to the standard?

Comment: Pretty sure that's going to be UB in any case as there is no `float` to alias here.

Comment: Yeah it's derived from the more "usual" `reinterpret_cast<float&>(variable)` pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conversion this `reinterpret_cast` expression seeks to perform is not among the list of conversions [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast) that a `reinterpret_cast` can perform [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#1). `0x7F800000` is a literal of integral type. The only conversion `reinterpret_cast` could perform that converts *from* a value of integral type to some other type is that of turning such a value into a pointer type [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#5). `float&&` is a reference type, not a pointer type. The only conversion `reinterpret_cast` can perform that converts *to* a reference type is that of converting a glvalue expression [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#11). `0x7F800000` is not a glvalue. Thus, this code is ill-formed. The fact that GCC would accept this is quite surprising to me and, I would say, definitely a bug that should be reported…

Comment: I thought so, thanks.
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86633